# Docusaurus avoids the generation of sites in the "static" folder

Tags: web, doxygen, docusaurus

I have a classic static Docusaurus site working fine.
I also generate a static Doxygen website.
When I open the Doxygen site only, the site is properly generated:
[image]

Now if I put the Doxygen website in the `static/code` folder of the Docusaurus project, the Doxygen files are properly moved at the root of my website after building Docusaurus project.

Now if I visit `mywebsite.com/code` I see the Doxygen website, but without any JS, and the logo isn't found, as you can see:

[image]

**How do I integrate another static site into a Docusaurus site? I don't need the Docusaurus layout for this other site, I just want it to work as if it were at the root of the site, but in a sub-folder.**

Comment: What / how are you exactly copying?

Comment: Doxygen generate many html and js in a folder. If I open his index.html with a browser all is fine. Docusaurus generate a React app that need to be use with a server (opening his index.html directly won't work). Now I have copied all files of Doxygen website in the folder `code`. If I go on `mywebsite.com` the Docusaurus site show, but if I go on `mywebsite.com/code` the Doxygen website show without js/img/etc.

Comment: Edit: If I do `mywebsite.com/code/index.html` or any other html page inside `code`, the file is not found. Yet `mywebsite.com/code` show the index.html (without js/img)

Comment: What are the types of the images (I know that e.g.g the doxygen logo is a SVG image)? Are there no images shown at all? It looks like it is the web server that is used that is blocking the js / image files or maybe some security policy.

Comment: It seams that it's a problem with relative path. Logo is in `www/code/logo.png`, html in in `www/code/index.html`, and logo is referenced in html with path `logo.png`. If I change path to `code/logo.png` it's working. So I think the server evaluate path as relative from root and not relative from html file

Comment: I think that this is a problem with the webserver as doxygen uses all relative paths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246454/discussion-between-maxime-charriere-and-albert).

Comment: I've nothing to add to the discussion at the moment. As I don't know the used server  and / or docusaurus (though you might want to look into https://docusaurus.io/docs/configuration).